# SVM - Can I normalize W vector?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

In SVM, there is something wrong with normalize W vector such:
`for each i W_i = W_i / norm(W)`
I confused. At first sight it seems that the result `sign(<W, x>)` will be same.  But if so, in the loss function  `norm(W)^2 + C*Sum(hinge_loss)` we can minimize W just by do `W = W / (large number)`.
So, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read either my minimal [5 ideas of SVMs](https://martin-thoma.com/svm-with-sklearn/) or better

> [Bur98] C. J. Burges, “[A tutorial on support vector machines for pattern recognition](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67119/svmtutorial.pdf)”, Data mining and knowledge discovery, vol. 2, no. 2, pp. 121–167, 1998.

To answer your question: SVMs define a hyperplane to seperate data. Hyperplanes are defined by a normal vector w and a bias b:

[image]

If you change only w, this will give another hyperplane. However, SVMs do more tricks (see my 5 ideas) and the weight vector actually is normalized to be in a relationship to the margin between the two classes.

Comment: Your "five ideas" is a pretty nice concise summary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing out on the constraint that 
r(wTx+w0)>=1 for all examples, thus normalizing the weight vector will violate this constraint.

In fact this constraint is introduced in the SVM in the first place to actually achieve a unique solution like else you mentioned there are infinite solutions possible just by scaling the weight vector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Actually, after the learning process there is something than prevent me from do W = W / ||W|| ?

Comment: If during inference on the test set, you use sign(wTx+w0) then normalization doesn't matter at all, however say incorrect classification is costly to you , and you want to compute the confidence you have in the classification and use a sigmoid for it= 1/1+e-(wTx+w0), so basically the farther you are from the boundary the more confident you are in the classification, normalization in this case is not a good idea. Visualize the scale of weights as defining the scale of the distance measure, while the normalized value(which defines the direction of weights vector) defines the boundary.